# Android | Unmarshalling Unknown Type while using Parcelable Data vai Intent

Tags: android, unmarshalling

I have two activity A and B able to send data from A to B, but getting    `android unmarshalling unknown type code` in class B.

This is My class A:

```
intent.putExtra("totalamount",total);

and in B im getting that value via
getIntent().getExtras("totalamount");
```

Comment: There aren't any getExtras(String) method. That should be getExtras().getString("totalamount") or something suitable for the type of totalamount

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
       extras.getFloat("totalamount"); // use the type of data in place of String
    }
```

Comment: im getting run time exception unmarshalling data while extras.getString("totalamount");

Comment: What is type of data in "totalamount". ?i mean what is total??

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the Parcelable object like that:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    extras.getParcelable("totalamount");
}
```